# R multinom (nnet) logistic regression prediction

Tags: r, predict, multinomial

I am going through "Applied Logistic Regression" by Hosmer, Lemeshow and Sturdivant, concretely chapter 8, multinomial logistic regression. I've built a model:

```
>library(nnet)  
>library(aplore3); data(aps)  
>fit <- multinom(place3 ~ danger, data = aps)
```

I got coefficients that match those in the book. My problem is when I try to make predictions: it just stacks **everything** in the level that is the most frequent in the data, and zero in other levels. I used code:

```
>preds <- predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(danger = aps$danger),type = "class")   
>table(preds)   
 OutDay    Int    Res    
  508       0      0
```

I've searched the web and got to the nice  [r-bloggers post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-multinomial-regression-models-in-r/) and the function described there kind of sorted the thing out, with the same fit I got

```
predictions  
Int OutDay    Res    
132    262    114
```

But I searched the web further because I wanted to read more about the use of the `predict` function with `multinom` so I ran into some examples like this one on [github](http://amunategui.github.io/multinomial-neuralnetworks-walkthrough/) where the poster uses `predict` in the straightforward way. I replicated the example and got everything OK.
My final question is if someone can explain when to use the `predict` with `multinom` object in the complicated (r-bloggers' post) way and when to use it in the straightforward way. Is the difference that in my example I am trying to get out fitted values for the data that was used to fit the model, or there's more to it?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome  to working with imbalanced data. Predicting by class depends on the threshold set for the decision criteria. This needs to be carefully tuned when working with real data.